# Can't map D+mousebuttons to navigate the viewport

Tags: customization, navigation, keymap

<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd> for zooming works great, but <kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> (rotate view) and <kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> (pan view) work in *Object Mode* but not in *Edit Mode*, where they get superseded by the contextual menu and regular selecting respectively (the original actions those mouse actions do without holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key).
I don't like to use modifiers on my pinky or the MMB for navigation. And I'm trying to make navigation work like [Softimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Softimage)'s.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Right mouse press have higher priority than any modifier key. So the only thing i can reccomend (and i use it):
MMB press to orbit, MMB scroll to zoom, RMB to pan, W (and 4th mb, and menu button) for context menu.

Or just change contextmenu to W and tune as you wish.

But yes, it is a question for developers, why D+RMB counts like RMB+D

Comment: I didn't find an entry to change the mapping for the edit mode contextual menu, though. Do you know where that is?

Comment: I suppose it can be assigned as more global.
edit mode = mesh.
Or just add entry